# woocommerce_quantity_input doesn't work in add to cart loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a quantity selection block in the add to cart loop on the product list page in woocommerce. Woocommerce codex has a page which allows me to do it by basically putting this block of code instead of the existing one:

```
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>

        <button type="submit" class="button alt"><?php echo $label; ?></button>

    </form>
```

However, that form doesn't add to my current AJAX setup and other nice tricks that come with my original add to cart button.
This is the original code of the add to cart button, which works like i want it, except for missing the quantity input:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $jckqv;

$jckqv->displayBtn($product->id); 

echo '<div class="product-buttons">';

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );

echo do_shortcode('[yith_compare_button]');
echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]');



echo '</div>';
```

I need to somehow put the **woocommerce_quantity_input** in this code, to retain the current functionality, but to add the quantity input. I tried to do it in many various ways, but unfortunately my PHP skills lack.
Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who might still need to use this

```html
        <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
```

You need to echo it. As easy as that